# yii framework in Update form display related model list (admin)

Tags: php, yii

**yii framework in Update form display related model list (admin)**

I have achieved the same. But Update and View links are current model name

I have four tables
Event 
 - has many task
 - has many agreement
 - has many attendants
 - has many tags
 - has many documents

Agreements, Attendants(Person of Company),Tags,Documents
 - All Associated with event_id

```
   **This Current Link** : http://localhost/event_tracking/trunk/**event**/update/1
   **Required Link :** http://localhost/event_tracking/trunk/**task**/update/1
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User renderPartial function in related model view.

```
echo $this->renderPartial('application.views.person.admin',array('model'=>$person_model));
```

Also worked as above

```
  echo $this->renderPartial('//person/admin',array('model'=>$person_model));
```